# Hibernate throws "QueryException" while compiling, although SQL is valid

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm facing a kind of strange problem and don't know in which direction to go to solve it ;-)

I'm currently developing a web application for storing employees using Hibernate.

Inserting, deleting, searching; everything works just fine.

But!
Every employee has a property represented by a list of Strings.

I want to search for one or for two or more entries in this property (it has to do with skills of the employee;

e.g: I search for "Databases" or for "Databases, Administration", which would bring up every employee that has "Databases" and "Administration" in his/her skillGroups-property).

If I search for just one skill group, everything works as expected. 
But when I try to search for two or more skill groups, Hibernate keeps on throwing a `QueryException`, although the generated SQL seems to be correct (if I execute it directly in the MySQL-Workbench, I get the expected result).

The exception is the following:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:231)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)  
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)  
org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)  
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

Following is the SQL I want to generate:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM employee.new_view 
 WHERE idemployee IN (
  SELECT idemployee 
    FROM employee.employee_skillgroups 
   WHERE idskillgroup = 'Sprachen')
 AND idemployee IN (
  SELECT idemployee 
    FROM employee.employee_skillgroups 
   WHERE idskillgroup = 'Services')
```

Comment: Are you using **HQL** or **SQL**? Publish the query you are using.

Comment: In this case I'm using SQL ... it generates me this query: SELECT * FROM `employee`.`new_view` WHERE `idemployee` IN (SELECT `idemployee` FROM `employee`.`employee_skillgroups` WHERE idskillgroup = 'Sprachen') AND `idemployee` IN (SELECT `idemployee` FROM `employee`.`employee_skillgroups` WHERE idskillgroup = 'Services');
But as i said before, in the MySqlWorkbench it works ... with Hibernate it doesn't ...

Comment: If I got you correctly, you want to use the **SQL**. Update the answer with the code you are using to call this query.

Comment: Now I got the task to do everything using Spring and HibernateTemplate; how do i get the result of a search for two skill group using this? :D I'm trying for hours now and i bet it's as simple as the answer to my first question, but i just don't get it ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use `session.createSQLQuery(sqlString)` not `session.createQuery(sqlString)` when creating your query.

Comment: Yepp, that was it ._. You can't imagine how stupid i feel right now .... Thank you veeery much for helping me out with this! :)

Comment: It's easily done - for future reference you can tell by the stacktrace - 'HQLQueryPlan' is a dead giveaway!